# Get all documents with specific properties in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

Good morning everybody,

Today I'm facing with mongoose queries.

Let's suppose we have the following collection:

```
[
   {letter: "A", name: "Books", action: "read"},
   {letter: "B", name: "Notebook", action: "write"},
   {letter: "C", name: "Camera", action: "take photos"},
   {letter: "D", name: "Pencil", action: "draw"}
]
```

I'd like to get a sub-collection with the documents with name: "Books" and name: "Pencil".

Desired output:

```
[
       {letter: "A", name: "Books", action: "read"},
       {letter: "D", name: "Pencil", action: "draw"}
]
```

Is it possible using the "find()" method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$in` operator

```
db.collection.find({
  name: {
    $in: [
      "Books",
      "Pencil"
    ]
  }
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gtfdjc-5QLJ)**

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Another version of `find` using `$or` operator.

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "name": "Books"
    },
    {
      "name": "Pencil"
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/__apWZ4-LNr) for you.

Comment: Thanks also to you, it's another way to accomplish what I wanted